# Why use WebRTC/similar libraries?

Tags: android, webrtc, voip

Currently have a functioning android app where users can message, send files, and video call each other. This is implemented via sending objects over plain old Java sockets (TCP). From a bit of research it seems like existing softwares (e.g. Discord or Signal) use WebRTC or their own fork/similar libraries.

Given that Discord was initially developed using a web technologies (React stack) and then converted over to native with Electron or React Native, the use of WebRTC makes sense. But for my use case, is there an innate advantage to using said libraries, whether that be scalability, security, etc, or would I be fine with my implementation?

Comment: Video calls over TCP require a very good network connection; WebRTC adds, first of all, resilience to communication conditions.

Comment: Doesn't WebRTC do this by leveraging UDP? If so, isn't the resilience more a product of something not intrinsic to WebRTC itself and it can be implemented separately?

Comment: Building your own communication service over UDP is not easy; adding FEC and bandwidth control (which includes tuning the camera and the encoder) makes this task worth a few man-years.

Answer (score 4):

WebRTC provides a few things that aren't possible with media over TCP (or is difficult to implement)

Real-time communication is difficult over TCP because of backpressure/congestion feedback. TCP has reliable delivery. You can depend on everything arriving, but you don't get enough feedback. With UDP communication you can measure jitter/packet loss/RTT and adjust the bitrate of the media. This makes sure you are only sending what your network supports and you can keep the call real-time.

WebRTC has mandatory security. If you use WebRTC you get DTLS+SRTP. You can implement this with TLS over your TCP connection of course. It is just having it all done for you.

WebRTC has P2P. You can do NAT Traversal and connect two peers and not have to route any media through a 3rd party server. TCP NAT Traversal is possible, but I have never seen it done myself.

WebRTC is available everywhere. With a TCP protocol you need to implement code on each new platform. With WebRTC I have SDKs already available for C, C++, C#, Go, Python and Typescript. I can get up and running pretty much anywhere very easily.

It is hard to understand what WebRTC really is because it is both an API, protocol and a library. Check out WebRTC for the Curious' [What is WebRTC?](https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/01-what-why-and-how/). There is a lot of value that just isn't apparent at first, if you have any feedback would love to hear.

Comment: Of all the features you mention here, TCP NAT is the least. But overall, this is a good summary.

Comment: ice-tcp doesn't work for for NAT traversal in practice. Its support in WebRTC is generally with servers, two browsers can not even talk tcp to each other directly.